# flutter sliding_up_panel plugin how to jumpTo top of panel on close?

Tags: flutter, plugins, controller, sliding

I'm using Flutter's [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) & my app has a glitch.

I have a Googlemap as the back panel, When you select a location from the app drawer it animates the map camera to a marker, and the sliding up panel 'peeks', revealing the top of the panel, using the panel's `minHeight:` property.  If the peek interests, the user can then choose to pull up to reveal more detail on the marker location, contained in a ListView.

The problem comes if the users selects a new location from the app drawer.  The panel closes, the Map camera animates to the new marker, then the panel provides a 200px panel peek for the new location, but the scroll position is preserved from the prior panel's details.  So I can have a peek that's supposed to show the title of the new Marker position, but in fact shows a slither of picture, or text half way down the panel.

I've tried using
`slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);`
To jump the panel ListView to the top, but Android Studio Logcat says

```
ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 171 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty'
```

Clearly, I don't understand how to attach SlidingPanel's ScrollController to the panel's ListView.  My understanding of controllers could be improved.

Help appreciated.

```
SlidingUpPanel(
        key: Key("slidingUpPanelKey"),
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(8)),
        parallaxEnabled: true,
        controller: slidingPanelController,
        onPanelOpened: () async {
          setState(() {
            panelMinHeight = 0;
          });
          },
        onPanelClosed: () {
          slideUpPanelScrollController.jumpTo(0);
        },
        minHeight: panelMinHeight,
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height,
        panelBuilder: (slideUpPanelScrollController) => _scrollingList(slideUpPanelScrollController, presentLocation),
        body: Animarker(
          // Other properties
          curve: Curves.ease,
          //markers: animatedMarkerMap.values.toSet(),
          isActiveTrip: false,//rippleAnimationActive,
          rippleRadius: 0.1,  //[0,1.0] range, how big is the circle
          rippleColor: myColorSwatch.gold, // Colors.teal Color of fade ripple circle
          rippleDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 2600), //Pulse ripple duration
          shouldAnimateCamera: false, // TODO stops weird camera centering movement?
          mapId: _mapController.future.then<int>((value) => value.mapId),
          child: GoogleMap(
            key: Key("myGoogleMap"),
            mapType: MapType.hybrid,
            initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
            //TODO markers: _markers,
            markers: animatedMarkerMap.values.toSet(),
            circles: mapCircles, // used for highlighting a location selected from the drawer
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            zoomControlsEnabled: false, // TODO would prefer them on screen, but 1/2 off!
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              print("GoogleMaps onMapCreated fired");
              _mapController.complete(controller);
            },
        ),
        ),
      ),
```

I attach the ScrollController to the ListView here:

```
  Widget _scrollingList(ScrollController slideUpPanelScrollController, LocationDetails presentLocation) {
    return ListView(controller: slideUpPanelScrollController,
        key: Key("scrollingPanelListView"),
        children: [...
```

The Sliding Panel should show the top of it's ListView, with a draggable indicator, title, subtitle like so
[image]

But if I open a new location from the app drawer, squirting a new location's data into the panel, it doesn't reset the Panel's ScrollPosition, it maintains it, showing the user info half way down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you attach the slideUpPanelScrollController to the ListView:

```
ListView(
  controller: slideUpPanelScrollController
```

Comment: Cheers for your attention Jim!  Yes I have.  It's called in the line ```panelBuilder: (slideUpPanelScrollController) => _scrollingList(slideUpPanelScrollController, presentLocation),``` & I've appended a snippet of code showing the ScrollController being assigned to the ListView's controller property.  Would it matter that the SlidingPanel has called a method to build it's ListView / panel?  Would that somehow interfere with the attachment?  I made ```slideUpPanelScrollController``` a global variable for the whole class so I can use the ScrollController method ```jumpTo(0)``` anywhere.